# Can I route express controllers and basic nodejs server in seperate modules

Tags: node.js, express

I have a requirement. denpends on the HOST header using different module,  just like  www.myhost.com using expressjs, and *.h.myhost.com using basic nodejs https.createServer(). And they are works in same port.

```
https.createServer(options,function(req, res){
   if(req.host === "www.myhost.com"){
       express.handle(req,res) //what I hope
       return 
   }
   //handle by normal way
})
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) by nodejitsu. I use it to deploy and configure multiple applications running under different subdomains.

Example:

```
var express = require('express'),
  https = require('https'),
  proxy = require('http-proxy');

// define proxy routes
var options = {
  router: {
    'www.myhost.com': '127.0.0.1:8001',
    '*.h.myhost.com': '127.0.0.1:8002'
  }
};

// express server for www.myhost.com
var express = express.createServer();

// register routes, configure instance here
// express.get('/', function(res, req) { });

// start express server
express.listen(8001);

// vanilla node server for *.h.myhost.com
var vanilla = https.createServer(options,function(req, res){
  // handle your *.h.myhost.com requests
}).listen(8002);

// start proxy
var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(options);
proxyServer.listen(80);
```

I'm not sure about using wildcards in the http-proxy routing table (*.h.myhost.com), but since these values are converted to regular expressions in node-http-proxy, i assume they work.

Comment: No, but thanks for the great node-http-proxy. I use express vhost to resolve my problem.